# flash write efm32zg fails with while (DMA->CHENS & DMA_CHENS_CH0ENS)

Tags: ram, bootloader, keil, rom, flash-memory

I am attempting to create a boot loader which allows me to update a processor's software remotely.
I am using keil uvision compiler (V5.20.0.0).

**Flash.c**, **startup_efm32zg.s**, **startup_efm32zg.c** and **em_dma.c** configured to execute from RAM (code, Zero init data, other data) via their options/properties tabs.

Stack size configured at `0x0000 0800` via the startup_efm32zg.s Configuration Wizard tab.

Using Silicon Labs flash.c and flash.h, removed `RAMFUNC` as this is redundant to Keil configuration, above.

I modified the flash.c code slightly so it stays in the FLASH_write function (supposedly in RAM) until the DMA is done doing its thing.

I moved the 
    while (DMA->CHENS & DMA_CHENS_CH0ENS);
line down to the end of the function and added a little wrapper around it like this:
    /* Activate channel 0 */
    DMA->CHENS = DMA_CHENS_CH0ENS;

```
if (DMA->CHENS & DMA_CHENS_CH0ENS)
{
  /* Start the transfer */
  MSC->WRITECMD = MSC_WRITECMD_WRITETRIG;
  /* Wait until transfer is done */
  while (DMA->CHENS & DMA_CHENS_CH0ENS)
  {
    //do nothing here
  }
}
```

`FLASH_init()` is called as part of the initial setup prior to entering my infinite loop.

When called upon to update the flash.....

**(1)**: I disable interrupts.

**(2)**: I call `FLASH_erasePage` starting at `0x0000 2400`.  This works.

**(3)**: I call `FLASH_write`.

```
FLASH_write(&startAddress, (uint32_t *)flashBuffer, (BLOCK_SIZE/4));
```

Where:
`startAddress = 0x00002400`,
`flashBuffer = a buffer of type uint8_t flashBuffer[256]`,
`#define BLOCK_SIZE = 256`.

It gets stuck here in the function:

```
while (DMA->CHENS & DMA_CHENS_CH0ENS)
```

Eventually the debugger execution stops and the Call Stack clears to be left with 0x00000000 and ALL of memory is displayed as 0xAA.

I have set aside 9K of flash for the bootloader. After a build I am told:

> Program size: Code=7524 RO-data=304 RW-data=664 ZI-data=3432

Target Memory Options for Target1:
`IROM1: Start[0x0] Size[0x2400]`
`IRAM1: Start[0x20000000] Size:[0x1000]`

So .... what on earth is going on?  Any help?

One of my other concerns is that it is supposed to be executing from RAM.  When I look in the  in the Call Stack for the Location/Value for FLASH_write after having stepped into the FLASH_write function I see 0x000008A4. This is flash!(?)

I've tried the whole RAM_FUNC thing, too with the same results.